# Is there a way to speed up Hibernate Schema Validation?

Tags: performance, hibernate, validation, schema, ddl

I am running a hibernate schema validation at the server startup. I also have a test case that can trigger the schema validation.

This is done by setting the following property on hibernate configuration.

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate
```

I have a about 3600 entities that need to be validated, but the schema validation is taking somewhere between 20 and 30 minutes. I have debugged through the code, and most of the time taken is within the hibernate framework.

I was wondering if there is a way to speed up validation (eg. parallel processing of the tables) or via some other properties.